# where clause returns empty set even when using trim

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried over and over to get a very simple query to work. Its part of login sequence, but any time I use the 'WHERE' clause it returns an empty set. For example

```
SELECT email, password FROM `users`
```

will work. But this fails :

```
SELECT email,password FROM `users` WHERE email='stevebushe@gmail.com'
```

Using TRIM or using replace() to make sure there are no spaces,line breaks or returns. I'd appreciate any help, this little problem has held me up for days.

Comment: This needs more context, show us an example or the output without the where that matches... Is email varchar?

Comment: Yes email is varchar. The encoding is utf8_unicode_ci . The incoming data is trimmed before being inserted in the database. the example query that fails is literally exactly what im putting into phpMyAdmin.And the response I get is : "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0013 sec )". The is query  'Select email, password from `users' returns the following :

Comment: SQL query: select email, password from users LIMIT 0, 30 ;
Rows: 2
email password
"stevebushe@gmail.com" "952d46237c5faaf4b920a925e0619321597105fff2bc44235ddd022bf7b34fd0"
"steve@eclecticdigital.com" "56fa59c3b0a3598d24a261c75c895a3c7a10672a2c9c3380b25d42c9fdaefc11"

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The issue was quotation marks. Used concat and trim together to change the values in 'email' column and now everything works.